# How prove this the vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an element of $SO_{3}$,show that if it is defined,the vector
$$((a_{23}+a_{32})^{-1},(a_{13}+a_{31})^{-1},(a_{12}+a_{21})^{-1})^T$$
is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$

I found this [Closed-form for eigenvectors of rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/closed-form-for-eigenvectors-of-rotation-matrix)

I kown this: ifIf $A \in SO_{3}(R)$, then $A$ has an eigenvalue  $\lambda=1$, see page 22
the proof:https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mathclub/cheat_sheets/notes.150B.pdf

But I can't prove my problem ,Thank you

Comment: Hello,you link we don't open it

Comment: This is a direct consequence of [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on user1551’s comment : since $A$ is an element of $SO_3$, it is a 
rotation around an axis. Let $\overrightarrow{k}=(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ be a directing vector for the axis and call $\theta$ the angle.

Then, Rodrigues’ formula (proved on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)) tells us
that for any vector $\overrightarrow{x}$ ,

$$
A\overrightarrow{x}=(\cos(\theta))\overrightarrow{x}+
(\sin(\theta))(\overrightarrow{k} \wedge \overrightarrow{x})+
(1-\cos(\theta))(\overrightarrow{k}.\overrightarrow{x}) \overrightarrow{k} \tag{1}
$$

And hence

$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 & -k_3\sin(\theta) & k_2\sin(\theta) \\
k_3\sin(\theta) & 0 & -k_1\sin(\theta) \\
-k_2\sin(\theta) & k_1\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k_1^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_1k_2(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_1k_3(1-\cos(\theta)) \\
k_1k_2(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_2^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_2k_3(1-\cos(\theta)) \\
k_1k_3(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_2k_3(1-\cos(\theta)) & k_3^2(1-\cos(\theta)) \\
\end{array}
\right) \tag{2}
$$

We deduce that for $i\neq j$,

$$
a_{ij}+a_{ji}=2k_ik_j(1-\cos(\theta)), \text{so} \
\frac{1}{a_{ij}+a_{ji}}=\lambda k_{6-(i+j)} \tag{3}
$$

where $\lambda$ is the constant $\frac{k_1k_2k_3}{2(1-\cos(\theta))}$. The result is now clear.